# LOCATION SERVICES authorization in settings in ios8

Tags: authorization

Hi everyone i am facing strange issue regarding Location services authorization for my ios app
In Settings.even i selected  always available option in  Location services for my app, but after killing the seetings App and after again checking for location services settings for my app is changing to unselect state.

Comment: what do you mean by "unselect state"?  Do you mean the app prompts again for permission to use Location Services?

Comment: app doesnot prmpts, but in my app Location delegates are not calling,so i came back to Settings for check Location permissions for my app its showing, switchoff mode (permission switch button in offState ) @MichaelDautermann